# Object reference not set to an instance of an object - exception

Tags: xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Xml.xml");
```

I am trying to load a XML document, but I get an exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

The main purpose is to make a list from all the objects in the xml with

```
AllUsers = doc.Descendants("EventUser").Select(d =>
                    new EventUser
                    {
                        Name = d.Element("Name").Value,
                        Day = doc.Element("Day").Value,
                        Month = doc.Element("Month").Value,
                        Year = doc.Element("Year").Value
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Show us what the XML looks like!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try without value like code below.  If the tag doesn't exist you will get the error with your original code.  Check the uppcase/lower case of the tag names to make sure they are correct

```
AllUsers = doc.Descendants("EventUser").Select(d =>
                    new EventUser
                    {
                        Name = (string)d.Element("Name"),
                        Day = (int)doc.Element("Day"),
                        Month = (int)doc.Element("Month"),
                        Year = (int)doc.Element("Year")
                    }).ToList();​
```